# Strict inclusions in spectral mapping theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let X be a complex Banach space and $T \in L(X)$. Spectral mapping theorem states that for any complex polynomial p
$$\sigma(p(T)) = p(\sigma(T)). $$
When I was analysing the proof of this theorem I managed to show that for continuous spectrum $\sigma_C$, residual spectrum $\sigma_R$ and approximate point spectrum $\sigma_{AP}$ we get one side inclusions of this theorem, namely
$$ \sigma_i (p(T)) \subset p(\sigma_i(T)),$$
for $i \in \{AP,R,C\}$.

I managed to show that for $\sigma_C$ this inclusion is strict, by studying spectrum of a multiplication operator on $\ell^2$ (in my example $\lambda \in \sigma_C(T)$, but $\lambda^2 \in \sigma_P(T^2)$. I would like to find similar examples for residual spectrum, and perhaps for approximate point spectrum, but unfortunately here I'm stuck. I feel like this inclusion will be strict for residual spectrum, but I'm not that confident about approximate point spectrum (I didn't manage to prove the opposite inclusion for this part of spectrum thought).

I would appreciate any help regarding this!

Just to be clear, I consider the following definitions (from Kreyszig's book):
$$\sigma_C := \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}: T - \lambda \text{ is 1-1}, \operatorname{range}(T - \lambda) \text{ is dense}, (T - \lambda)^{-1} \text{ is unbounded} \},$$
$$
\sigma_R := \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}: T - \lambda \text{ is 1-1}, \operatorname{range}(T - \lambda) \text{ is not dense}\},$$

$$\sigma_{AP} := \{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}: \lVert (T-\lambda)x_n\rVert \rightarrow 0 \text{ for some } (x_n) \subset X \text{ such that } \lVert x_n \rVert = 1, n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$

Comment: You can not hope to get strict inclusion in general. For a simple reason, take $p(z)=z$ to be the identity polynomial. Then $p(T)=T.$ In fact more generally, for any polynomial of degree $1,$ you will always get exact equality. Secondly, as you already mentioned the spectral theorem tells you that $\sigma(p(T))=p(\sigma(T)),$ so if you get strict inclusions in all three kinds of spectrums it will violate the Spectral mapping theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Will 3 strict inclusions really violate the spectral mapping theorem? I'm familiar with relations between those sets, but I was thinking about a situation where objects from $p(\sigma_i(T))$ for $i \in \{ AP, C, R\}$ are perhaps "shifted" between those sets (they can "appear" in a different set after applying polynomial $p$) if we assume strict inclusions, even thought they will still be parts of $p(\sigma(T))$ so equality for the general spectrum will hold.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add @WhoKnowsWho, I'm still new to this site :) (although I'm not sure if it's necessary in this situation)

Comment: What is your example for strict inclusion of continuous spectrum?

Comment: @sas I considered $p(z)=z^2$ and multiplication operator $M_a \in L(\ell^2)$ given by $M_a(x)=ax$ where $a=(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty = (1-\frac{2}{n})_{n=1}^\infty $. Then $1 \in \sigma_C(M_a)$ so $1=1^2 \in (\sigma_C(M_a))^2$ but $(-1)^2=1 \notin \sigma_C(M_a^2)$ (here $M_a^2$ will just give $M_{a^2}$).

Comment: Why $1\not\in\sigma_C(M^2_a)$? It is in spectrum, certainly not in residual part.

Comment: @sas A property of a multiplication operator states that the point spectrum $\sigma_P (M_b)$ is given by $\{b_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ (so basically the elements of the sequence building this multiplication operator, here $b=(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$). But since in our case for $b=a^2$ we get that for $n=2$ we have $(a_n)^2 = (-1)^2=1$ hence $1 \in \sigma_P(M_{a^2})$ and since continuous and point spectra are disjoint thus $1 \notin \sigma_C(M_{a^2})$ as claimed. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: @sas, sorry, I meant $n=1$, not $n=2$!

Comment: Yeah, got it. As polynomial function preserves point spectrum, and $x\to x^2$ 'glues' $-1$ and $1$, the point $1$ becomes point spectrum.